# Use generic type in function returns Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'T'

Tags: typescript, types, generic-type-argument

I want to convert the keys of a document to camelCase.

This was working fine with an `unknown` type, but at the end of the day, I need the type provided to perform operations later.

```
camelizeKeys(strings).map(() =>...); // <- Object is of type 'unknown'. ts(2571)
```

I decided to update the function with generic typings, getting the following errors (note that this works with `unknown` instead of `T`):
[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhA8gIwFYFNiwLwwBQBuAhgDYCu6AXDGWANZggDuYAlNceevBDAEqYQAJwAmAHmhC4YAOYAaGvUYsAfDGxqA3gCgYe+ADN8nCutxgyJEqxg799mEPRQyQsDAOkI6ANy79AL7+ek4ubjBQAJ4ADuggRibc2MkwAOQgaJhQqX5B2qCQsMBEALboJADCRN7q+BDUktIy7DCNsupqEH754NAwxWUkcABe6ADS6JG8uGIAKjDoAB5Q6GAivLQMzGAqeBmo1LMt8xq2wYb4AIJCQkSRAHQI17eRe2isNnYOIc6u7vv3EpEaJ4Qg2U4DcojcaTCBg1h+ewBBYkGpwIx4BAoDBYN6oD5nb4-MLubFZe50WF41j3JwiMjAdB4c5E-BOCCWKAKSmRcFqPBfVnfe4i9mcuQsoV6ADakMq1SZPNYAF1qHLoRMpnjpTzlaxJd8AqwJVK9JogqyEecLfpQn8YPtcn4gA)

```
const isObject = (value: unknown): value is Record<string, unknown> => {
    if (value == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return typeof value === 'object';
}

const camelCase = (s: string): string => s;

const camelizeKeys = <T extends unknown>(obj: T): T => {
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        return obj.map((v) => camelizeKeys(v)); // <- Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    } else if (isObject(obj)) {
        return Object.keys(obj).reduce( // <- Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'.
            (result, key) => ({
                ...result,
                [camelCase(key)]: camelizeKeys(obj[key])
            }),
            {}
        );
    }
    return obj;
};
```

Thanks in advance and happy coding!

Comment: The complaints are valid. Assuming your `camelCase` function actually camelCases the string (not that typescript can know that it doesn't actually camelCase the string since your typing is just `string => string`), an input of `{"foo bar": string}` gets transformed into `{fooBar: string}`, which isn't the same type.

Comment: Then how can I fix this for it to work and return the type? The camelCase function is ilustrational btw :)

Comment: You have to keep your promise with annotations. Return the type you have annotated. and if its multiple types use | to union them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general case, the compiler will not be able to verify that the implementation of `camelizeKeys()` will transform the input value of type `T` into an output value of type `CamelizeKeys<T>` where `CamelizeKeys` describes the type of such transformation.  In your example, `CamelizeKeys<T>` would just be a no-op `T`, I guess, but below I will present a version that actually turns `snake_case` into `CamelCase` (*upper* camel case, because that's easier).  Regardless:

Inside the implementation of `camelizeKeys()`, the generic type parameter `T` is *unspecified* or *unresolved*. It could be any `T` at all, for all the compiler knows.  Even if you check the type of `obj`, the compiler cannot use that information to narrow the type parameter `T` (see [microsoft/TypeScript#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) and [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085) for discussion on this).  There are very few cases in which the compiler can verify that a particular value is assignable to anything related to an unspecified generic type parameter.  Most of the time, and in general, the compiler will often complain that what you are doing isn't known to be safe.  (See [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) for a discussion of unresolved *conditional* generic types; I'm not sure there's a canonical issue for the general case of all unresolved generics... lots of related issues like [microsoft/TypeScript#42493](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42493) but I haven't found anything I'd call definitive.)

---

So, generic functions that do arbitrary manipulation of their input type will often need to be implemented with heavy use of [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), or the like, to work around this.  It means that the *implementer* of the function has the responsibility to guarantee type safety, since the compiler cannot.

---

As an example, let me rewrite `camelCase()` this way:

```
type CamelCase<T extends string> = T extends `${infer F}_${infer R}`
    ? `${Capitalize<F>}${CamelCase<R>}` : Capitalize<T>;

const camelCase = <T extends string>(s: T): CamelCase<T> =>
    s.split("_").map(x => x.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x.slice(1)).join("") as any;
```

Here I'm using [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to turn string snake case literal types like `"foo_bar"` into the analogous camel case literals like `FooBar`.  So `camelCase()` acts on a value of type `T extends string` and returns a value of type `CamelCase<T>`.  Note that I had to use a type assertion `as any` here because again, the compiler has no way to follow the logic of the implementation to determine if it matches the typings.

Then, `CamelizeKeys<T>` will be a recursive mapped type with [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types):

```
type CamelizeKeys<T> = T extends readonly any[] ? 
{ [K in keyof T]: CamelizeKeys<T[K]> } : {
  [K in keyof T as K extends string ? CamelCase<K> : K]: CamelizeKeys<T[K]>
}
```

And the implmentation of `camelizeKeys()` is the same, but I give it a strongly typed call signature and a type assertion in every `return`:

```
const camelizeKeys = <T,>(obj: T): CamelizeKeys<T> => {
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        return obj.map((v) => camelizeKeys(v)) as any as CamelizeKeys<T>;
    } else if (isObject(obj)) {
        return Object.keys(obj).reduce(
            (result, key) => ({
                ...result,
                [camelCase(key)]: camelizeKeys(obj[key])
            }),
            {} as CamelizeKeys<T>
        );
    }
    return obj as any as CamelizeKeys<T>;
};
```

So that compiles with no error. Again, the caveat is that if we made a mistake in the implementation, the compiler will not notice.  Anyway, let's test it:

```
const foo = camelizeKeys({
    prop_one: "hello",
    prop_two: { prop_three: 123 },
    prop_four: [1, "two", { prop_five: "three" }] as const
})

console.log(foo.PropOne.toUpperCase()); // HELLO
console.log(foo.PropTwo.PropThree.toFixed(2)); // 123.00
console.log(foo.PropFour[0].toFixed(2)); // 1.00
console.log(foo.PropFour[1].toUpperCase()); // TWO
console.log(foo.PropFour[2].PropFive.toUpperCase()); // THREE
```

This all works as expected. The compiler sees that `foo` has properties named `PropOne`, `PropTwo`, and `PropFour`, and all subproperties are similarly transformed, both at runtime and at compile time.  There may well be edge cases, of course, but this is the general approach I would take for something like this.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhA8gIwFYFNiwLwwBQBuAhgDYCu6AXDGWANZggDuYAlNceevBDAEqYQAJwAmAHmhC4YAOYAaGvUYsAfDGxqA3gCgYe+ADN8nCutxgyJEqxg799mEPRQyQsDAOkI6ANy79AL7+ek4ubjBQAJ4ADuggRibc2MkwAOQgaJhQqX4BMNraUbEwAMJEALboJGXeYgAqMOgAHlDoYCK8ktIyargNza3tvAAGACSa0gboQjAAYgEA+uOT0-wBw8EwAPwwY5pl0XBQpHAAXuhisyoB42WV1US1fNfDMNQHRyfn9Sp+2qCQWDACpVGpJGD1RotNodGBdWQqPAQah1dilEEPWp1XoqTYQAB0EGiJCOeAARAsyax8eUiNE8E11GomvjgAALIhCACCUDwAAZqVAQABVaKxIRgvA2ADUMBZEBJwHQeAAjKxqagQNJyVSYI89WBIn8itw7lUzugANLoSIQH7qGD9aFDRzoIgicAkSIGyIAbQAuttbDBfZb4O46Db4o7-e8MRbrbb6qH-Wo8tQ7PpQ+GYJHItGGvqwwMYZ0oFJZEGzZiLpa1NRLbH0fcEza7XUU7igv9wNAYMCW+dE7xcPU5IiMqgUWjq62k9imbZNnAjHguUIhERIviEOvN5E8JP1UuHPpQq53JOaXS8IQbBp+-Gh227zZ9URDXreLPn-Pfps8iqbxDHwBAUAwLBDzQY9M1Pc9wnArJ8TzCAoNQaknBEMglTwTZTz0PAnAgSwoAUPN7zUPBYPw098TooiSLkPCaKzAdQUeZVyKbNiSV-VDJ19PN-VYZjTwCVgmJY-RNDyfUfytNsflEmBWD8ewgnseDLzQL8fV0+Thx+XI-gBPsDBAEAHR4udUOo6IhBAaIFnAKgYDJNkqhIEAyUk-R7MchYoCYEAMxgfynKgNknFclUACYAGYYACXy9HChZzNcahfRVBQySC7yFE0MKHKcgw4AIVy8qi9B0DJJLA31UyoG0cSe0gEASHQfEvJkPBzJAfEAAUSsQMAuqFUVxUldUfBgAB6OaYAACQAUQAGTWxA2ogDqup6vqLKGkq6mCo7HLqarxpAWY4CadARDwWKZvmxa4vi-E+T5bbdu6kBev6s7olmEBXF9Pl-XxIUbruh6ntUl6YBVD6vtMn79oB4bHOB0GVQhiaxWmab4YWx0AHUttRzrfv+w7MaBkGhF9WKIbpm6KshkUCYlDipWJxa6iWvgVpW7QgA)

Comment: I think you are the TypeScript god. Thank you for such an answer! I've been years into TypeScript and never heard of such sorcery of types.

Answer (score 3):

The problem I see with typing here is, it seems like you have an overloaded function. The function returns an array if parameter is an array. The function returns an object if the parameter is object. Here is my way to skin the cat.

```ts
const isObject = (value: unknown): value is Record<string, unknown> => {
  if (value == null) {
    return false;
  }
  return typeof value === "object";
};

const isArray = (value: unknown): value is unknown[] => {
  return Array.isArray(value);
};

const camelCase = (s: string): string => s;

function camelizeKeys<T>(obj: T): T;
function camelizeKeys<T>(obj: T[]): T[];
function camelizeKeys<T>(obj: any): any {
  if (isArray(obj)) {
    return obj.map((v) => camelizeKeys(v));
  } else if (isObject(obj)) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce(
      (result, key) => ({
        ...result,
        [camelCase(key)]: camelizeKeys(obj[key]),
      }),
      {} as T
    );
  }
  return obj;
}
```

It nags me a bit that `camelizeKeys<T>(o: T)` is returning type T. In reality that may not be the case. In fact, the function should return a type something like `CamelizedType<T>`. Something like what Template Literal Types does in TypeScript 4.1 onwards. I could not find the discussion, but [Exploring Template Literal Types in TypeScript 4.1](https://davidtimms.github.io/programming-languages/typescript/2020/11/20/exploring-template-literal-types-in-typescript-4.1.html) looks like something what I want to convey.

[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/GNl5Bm)